# remove data from a svn synchronized git repository

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

we have a fairly huge svn repository that i access using git. so far everything was working fine. now someone accidentally added some huge chunks of binary data to the svn repository. (hundreds of MB!)
of course git also sucked in those chunks (using git-svn).

Is there a way to **selectively remove some files from git** *without* disturbing the synchronization with the svn repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost forgot about this...sorry.

as it turns out there is no easy solution to the problem that i described. i experimented with several options but each has drawbacks... nevertheless, maybe it is helpful if anybody else has the same problem:

**delete the unwanted file/folder from the git history**

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "[ -f hugefile.bin ] && rm hugefile.bin" -f
```

Pros:

- effectively removes the file from your repository

Cons:

- you will have to clean up your repository (get rid of the old commits as they are still in the git repo). either s.th. along `git gc --prune=now` or just clone your repository (will by default not clone your remote svn branch)
- the branch you get will not be synchronized with svn anymore (if you do another `git svn fetch` git will still fetch the unchanged history

---

**cut of the history of svn when initially cloning**

```
git svn clone -r N http://yoursvnaddress myPartlyClonedRepo.git
```

where N will be the earliest revision number that is synched

Pros:

- enables you to keep the size of your repository small (what I wanted in the first place)

Cons:

- earlier history is "lost"

---

**sparse checkout**

this has been a recent addition in git 1.7 and allows you to selectively modify your working directory

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo '!path-to-huge-unwanted-dir/' >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree -m -u HEAD
```

Pros

- easy setup

Cons

- does not affect the size of your database (.git)

Answer (score 1):

I believe rewriting git history using `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf unwanted_dir"`  wouldn't disturb the synchronization—as far as I can tell, `git-svn` only depends on the git-svn-ids in the commit messages, which should stay the same.  I haven't tried it, though. ☺

Comment: sounds a little scary...but still reasonable. i will give it a try with a cloned repo:)
thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

You could try using git svn's 'ignore path' to specify the name of the binaries that were added. You'd probably need to do an 'svn reset' to go back to the point in time in which they were added, and then filter the paths to remove these files.

Comment: NB this would have the effect of changing the history from the point of the SVN commit onwards, so other Git users would need to rebase off it after you've done this.

Comment: unfortunately this is not an option since i cannot change the svn history anymore